# What story is this? Contains sentient ships which can also make other ships

Tags: story-identification

I read this story quite some time back. I remember there were sentient ships. They may have been the main characters in the story with humans just passengers on those ships. One of the ships also manufactured other smaller ships which it then used to project its power or something like that. I think some of the ship types may have been called hunter killers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sentient ships is a very wide trope. As written, this could easily be one of the Culture novels, perhaps Excession?

Comment: The Culture series by Iain M Banks for sure.

Comment: Although the description "hunter killer" (or any hyphenated variant) doesn't appear in any of Bank's Culture books. In Excession and Surface Detail mention is made of "The Killer class Limited Offensive Unit".

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/228159/looking-for-a-novel-about-a-mysterious-sphere-cube-shaped-object (which is newer but self-answered by the original poster)

Answer (score 8):

My first guess on this would be the Culture novel "[Excession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excession)" by Iain M. Banks.

- **Sentient ships** - Check. This is a major theme of the novels
- **Humans are basically passengers** - Check. There are discussions between the ships about the various merits of carrying a human "crew" at all.
- **Hunter-Killer ships** - Check (kinda). "Killer"-class vessels are mentioned by name along with "Abominator"-, "Thug"- and "Torturer"-class vessels.
- **Ship projects power by creating other ships** - **Check.** The ending consists of learning that one of the ships has been involved in a...

> ...complex double-bluff to make people think it's gone loopy when it was actually spending its entire time manufacturing a veritable *cloud* of smaller ships.